# Does a Utility AI system run every update/frame to determine scoring?

Tags: ai

Am learning about Utility AI. I understand what it can be used for but not how to correctly implement it.

Does the scoring for an NPC need to be checked every frame/update/tick?

Imagine you have an NPC that patrols their area (default state), become alert when a player is in range (50ft), or shoot the player if the player gets close enough (25ft).

Does the scoring for the NPC get constantly checked for the NPC to be responsive?

I plan to have a lot of NPCs on the map at the same time in the same area, so concerns of all of them checking every frame seems that it could be quite heavy in regards to performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoid premature optimization! Recalculating all the scores each frame might in fact be a "good enough" solution, even with a hundred AI agents in the scene. I would recommend you to implement this first, do a stress-test while running a profiler, and see if it even shows up in the profiler log. When it doesn't, then everything is fine and you avoided a lot of work for no notable benefit.

But when it does turn out to be a performance bottleneck, then there are a couple optimizations you can do:

- Don't recalculate scores when the agent is in a situation where it can't change its behavior anyway. For example, when it's caught in an uninterruptible animation.
- Don't recalculate every frame, but every `n` frames. This might actually result in a more natural AI, because the AI will often react to changes in circumstances with a delay which simulates human reaction time. In this case you should do staggered updates (evaluate a different set of AI actors per frame). This also has the useful side-effect that not all AI actors will react on the exact same frame. So they won't act in a perfectly synchronized manner. Another nice trick is to modify `n` depending on distance to the player. Update those AI agents which are far away from the player less frequently than those which are nearby.
- Cache the scores for each AI agent and only recalculate them when an input variable actually changed.
- See what you can optimize regarding the input variables themselves. Some things which often feed into utility AI but can be real performance hooks are sightline calculations, pathfinding or environmental proximity queries. There is usually a lot of optimization potential in these.